# Android: getAngleChange - weird results

Tags: android, orientation, sensors, angle

I'm currently experimenting with some sensors of Android phones. For testing, I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S. As it does not have a gyroscope, I'm using accelerometer and sensor for magnetic field.

What I basically want to do, is to get a certain angle, when moving the device. I try to explain: consider you are holding the phone in landscape mode in front of your face and then you turn yourself by 90 degrees to the right.

I use the following code to get the current rotation matrix:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        mGravity = event.values.clone();
    }

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        mGeomagnetic = event.values.clone();
    }
    if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity,
                mGeomagnetic);
    }
}
```

This works well and then I use `SensorManager.getAngleChange(angleChange, R, lastR);` to achieve the angle change. 
I then get (roughly) 65° in `angleChange[1]` if I turn myself as described above and do not tilt the phone or change anything else...

But if I also tilt the phone by 90° when turning myself (so that display is looking to the ceiling afterwards) I get (roughly) 90° in `angleChange[1]`.

I'm very confused now, why such a rotation affects the value in `angleChange[1]` and on the other hand why it is needed to get the expected 90°.

What I want to achieve is to get the angle when moving the phone as described above (not in 90° degree steps but this sort of orientation change) no matter which other orientation changes (along the two other axes) are made.

Is there any possibility for this?

Comment: Another thing is, this method (SensorManager.getAngleChange()) is available from API Version 9, what could be the possible solution to get angle for earlier version supported devices.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I get your comment right. Are you asking for a different solution to get the angles if getAngleChange is not available due to older API versions?

Comment: Ya @fkerber. But i copied a method from source of API version 9 and working on it.

Comment: At the moment, I'm using equations from here: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roll-Nick-Gier-Winkel#Berechnung_aus_Rotationsmatrix
I'm sorry, the page is in German but I hope it's ok for the mathematial equations - the english version shows different equations.